# Extendible helper views in ember

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-view

So, I was hoping to be able to create a helper (master) view for my application, the main reason is that I want to implement a `resize` function.

Example.

```
App.View = Ember.View.extend({
    init: function() {
       $(window).resize(this.resize.bind(this));
       this._super();
    }
});
```

And then extend it

```
App.AmazingView = App.View.extend({
   resizing: false,
   resize: function() {
     this.set('resize', true);
   }
});
```

So, that's an example of what I wanted to achieve, but unfortunately it causes some problems.

If I go to the route that is using the `Amazing` view then everything works fine, it's only until you navigate around the application after and then **return** to that same route I face the following error.

> **Uncaught Error**: Something you did caused a view to re-render after it rendered but before it was inserted into the DOM.

I'm pretty sure this is happening because I'm extending that view, any ideas on why this happens or what I should actually be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sound like a feature that would fit perfectly into an ember mixin. This solution would offer more flexibility, then you could extend other views and also provide the resize features...

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html

Comment: Thanks, in fact I did try this, but turns out I was using `extend` instead of `create` on the `Mixin` `:)`

Answer (score 2):

When you do `$(window).resize(this.resize.bind(this));` you are attaching an event not managed for ember. When you leave the view, transitioning to other route, ember will cleanup event listeners and destroy the view. Now your view is in a "dead" state. But the resize handler is still present and when it triggers, a change is performed in a dead view. I think that it is causing your problem.

You can use the [didInsertElement](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_didInsertElement) and [willClearRender](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_willClearRender) to bind and unbind your event.

```
App.View = Ember.View.extend({
    _resizeHandler: null,
    didInsertElement: function() {
       this._super();
       // we save the binded resize function to keep the identity, so unbind will remove
       this._resizeHandler = this.resize.bind(this);
       $(window).bind('resize', this._resizeHandler);
    },
    willClearRender: function() {
       this._super();
       $(window).unbind('resize', this._resizeHandler);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem still persist's